# Word or phrase for "unsophisticated affectation" evoking lower-status associations

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

*Affectation* refers to a pretense intended to evoke higher-status associations. It apparently can't be used with lower-status associations. Google returns exactly one hit for "unsophisticated affectations", and it's a  rather poor one found in a literary criticism. (And a rare Googlewhack)

> Nakamura Mitsuo would observe after her death that Hayashi's garish tastes and unsophisticated affectations were themselves of the people (1957:24).
> [The Columbia Companion to Modern East Asian Literature, Joshua S. Mostow · 2003](https://books.google.com/books?id=TV4gtMoPXdUC&pg=PA160&lpg=PA160&dq=%22unsophisticated+affectations%22&source=bl&ots=O2b9yzHt2q&sig=ACfU3U3xwVLRe3a6VsXWwJPgU_O1QjiwWw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi-1r-z6ZzzAhVqSDABHR4XCnwQ6AF6BAgCEAM)

Now this is exactly the sense I am looking for. It is something a local politician or county fair huckster could deploy to good effect.

Is there a word or phrase for affecting a lower social association, and perhaps not very convincingly?

It might be done to entertain as Roy Rogers, Mark Twain, and Dan Whitney did, or to lure, gull, or dupe people.

Disaffectation has already been claimed and means something altogether different. Code shifting lacks the motives and directional specificity.